# Automatically modify clipboard content (regex pattern replacement) when copy-pasting

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed, clipboard

I'm often copying small separate text snippets and pasting them somewhere else. After that I always need to edit the pasted result in a well-defined way, which can be described through a regular expression replacement similar to e.g. `sed`'s `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` command.

I would like to automate the editing part of this task by having a script automatically processing the content of my clipboard buffer at some time between copying and pasting and modifying it by applying a configured regular expression replacement.

The actual regex pattern and replacement shall be entered by the user when the script gets launched and it also should somehow indicate that it is running though, e.g. by leaving a little dialogue window open and by sending a desktop notification each time a modification had been made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Introduction

The way question is posted, requires more than just having a simple script, but also a GUI interface for enabling/disabling the script. I've found that it would be easier to achieve via an Application Indicator that would be accessible from Ubuntu's top panel. This answer presents exactly that as a solution.

The `clipboard-autoedit-indicator` , which I've written specifically for this question, allows for automatic editing of clipboard contents based on a regex expression ( choice of `sed` or python's `re` style ). It uses Gtk's clipboard module and minimum dependencies, thus no need for installing additional tools such as `xclip` or `xsel`.

#### Installation

Run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:1047481448-2/sergkolo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clipboard-autoedit-indicator
```

#### Usage

The indicator can be launched by typing in Unity Dash `Clipboard Autoedit` or  via calling `/usr/bin/clipboard-autoedit-indicator` from command-line. There are two indicator icons (colored and grayed-out clipboard icon) to display when dynamic editing of the clipboard is enabled/disabled. When editing occurs, notification is sent to the user.

[image]

The "Set regex pattern" menu item calls `zenity` forms dialog.  When user edits regex rule, it is remembered and stored in `~/.clipboard-autoedit-config.json` file. The dynamic editing will be enabled automatically when user clicks <kbd>OK</kbd> button, but users can disable it via "Replacement Enabled" check menu item. The regex type defaults to python's `re` module.

[image]

#### Source code

The source code is available under the MIT license on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/clipboard-autoedit-indicator). Further development and newer versions will be there, and if you have a feature request and/or bug report, please submit them on GitHub.

Comment: That piece of software just froze my desktop session, and I had to kill it via another cli session.

Comment: @VadimKotov What exactly happened ?

Comment: Could not click any window, button, or close anything. Looked like my GUI session is frozen

Comment: @VadimKotov were there any error messages displayed ? Frozen GUI can occur for variety of reasons

Comment: No error messages were present. I could not open anything

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward with `xclip`. For the notifycation bit `notify-send` from the `libnotify-bin` package should suit your needs. You may need to install the packages first:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip libnotify-bin
```

Put the following into a script and make it runnable with a keybinding:

```
#!/bin/bash

xclip -o | sed 's/pat/repl/' | xclip -i
notify-send "Clipboard" "Replacement done"
```

Comment: I would like an automated solution though that does not require me to press an additional shortcut to perform the modification.

Comment: @ByteCommander: In that case you may want to look at [this python clipboard detector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25961646/1331399) and do the replacement within python.

Comment: It will modify everything that is selected, not just copied to clipboard. You'll need to use `xclip -o selection clipboard` and `xclip -i selection clipboard` to copy *from* and *to* clipboard.