# System-wide key-value store with fuzzy search

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, clipboard

I often have to access some pieces of data, e.g. my public ssh keys, ips of specific servers, links to repositories etc.

It would be great to have some application to store key-value mapping with fuzzy search that I could invoke with a system-wide hotkey and copy result into clipboard.

As an example: I press fn+S, search bar appears, I start typing "ssh" and list of my ssh keys appear, I select one of them with arrow keys, press Enter and value is copied into clipboard, now I can paste it where needed.

Comment: There are a couple of experts here in Ask Ubuntu who have written custom clipboard apps. Here is one of them: https://askubuntu.com/questions/873948/automatically-modify-clipboard-content-regex-pattern-replacement-when-copy-pas/875038#875038

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm not looking for a clipboard manager, I need a persistent store of some files/keys

Comment: I see. You are just looking for a mini-database with fuzzy logic search that can copy highlighted selection to clipboard.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, this database should either store values directly, or store links to files from which to copy the value (like ssh public key -> it should be a link to the file, and when I select it, file's content is copied)